# Clipboard listener service running in background on Android 2.1

Tags: android, service, background, clipboard

I'm trying to write an app that shows a message in the infobar when the clipboard is not empty. So I need some kind of clipboard listening service. I know that Android version 3.0 SDK contains a Clipboard Listener. But I need to implement it on version 2.1.

For example:

1. My app is running on background.
2. User has copied some text to the clipboard.
3. My service shows that text on infobar.

Any ideas?

Comment: hi, I have a question like your question for ´SDK 2.1´ . do you have any results? please answer me.I need this!

Comment: Yes! It was a long time ago. But I remember that I have done it using the background service, which was checking the clipboard every STEP_TIME.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I think(I haven't seen a project yet) [that](http://code.google.com/p/my-clips/) project can helps you.

Comment: I saw this project. But it has no functionality I needed. Also I've found the solution :) Just forgot to post it on my blog. I will do that tomorrow.

Comment: please post link of your blog so that it can help others